# how to save a encrypted image and read it later to get the original image back in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have an encrypted image where the contents are of the form

```
var image='p%ì3T!0!!0!-Ùg j\½+ÚïMür{-xüPOgm!45!!45!¬ÚñþÍ-¶ÎyP¢Ñàî!33!¢z·Ã-¹ÇóÌ¹ÅÖ{ôønÀ~-±µü¹«¬Ìò!34!d^ãø-h!0!æSkI^%»¯z¹-/¥ÖÀÇG¾sÂú-õadÑ7it4x±(¸ë-±ÝÅ){!45!Xº»±uÆ¼-¥®bÙeJû?PMú-%Ò!0!7!13!n5ZÙL«C-';
```

I am saving the image onto disk using

```
   function upload(image) {
   var b64Data= image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
var blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, 'image');

saveAs(blob, "hello world.jpg");

}
function b64toBlob(b64Data1, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;
  console.log('log2...');

  console.log(b64Data1);

  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data1);
  var byteArrays = [];

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
```

I am reading it using

```
 window.onload = function(){

//Check File API support
if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
{
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");
    //console.log(filesInput);
    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        console.log(files.length);
        var output1 = document.getElementById("result1");
        //console.log(output3);
      //  console.log(files);

        for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
        {
            var file = files[i];
          //  console.log(file);

            //Only pics
            if(!file.type.match('image'))
              continue;

            var picReader = new FileReader();

            picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                var picFile = event.target;

                var div1 = document.createElement("div1");

                div1.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";



            });

             //Read the image
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }                               

    });
}
else
{
    console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
}
  }
```

Next i am decrypting the ciphered data and saving it using the same first function...but i am not able to get the same image back.... it works fine when i don't save the cipher to a file but directly send to decrypting function...can anyone suggest in what encoding format i need to save the cipher to retain its original format so that i get the same image back

Comment: it seems as though the process should be: decode base64 > decrypt > original - perhaps your missing that first step?

Comment: I am decoding the base64 to utf-8 to get the original string back.....string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n"); var utftext = "";
for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
 var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
if (c < 128) {
utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);  }
else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128); }
else {
utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224); utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);}}But this doesn't seem to work.. why is this happening?

Comment: @shreya Sorry, but I don't see any encryption or decryption. Are you trying to get us to write that for you? If you're only having a problem with reading and writing image data, then you should make that clear and not bring encryption into it.